# How to create an occurrence counter in MySQL ,each time the counter find the id it occurrence increases?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'd like to count how many time each id occurred in the database using MYSQL
for the first time it reads the **ID** 100 it gives it 1 and for the fifth time it gives it 5 so each occurrence for each id is different

```
  ID   | occurrence 
  100  |   1
  200  |   1
  300  |   1
  200  |   2
  500  |   1
  100  |   2
  200  |   3
  600  |   1
```

.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ideally should have a third column which maintains the ordering of data you seem to be assuming above.  Assuming that a timestamp column `ts` exists, you could use `COUNT` here as an analytic function:

```sql
SELECT ID, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER by ts) occurrence
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY ts;
```

This assumes your data would look something like:

```
ID  | ts
100 | 2021-01-31 12:00:00
200 | 2021-01-31 13:00:00
300 | 2021-01-31 14:00:00
200 | 2021-01-31 15:00:00
500 | 2021-01-31 16:00:00
100 | 2021-01-31 17:00:00
200 | 2021-01-31 18:00:00
600 | 2021-01-31 19:00:00
```

This answer also assumes you are running MySQL 8+, and if not, consider upgrading.

Here is a version for MySQL 5.7:

```sql
SELECT
    ID,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourTable t2
     WHERE t2.ID = t1.ID AND t2.ts <= t1.ts) occurrence
FROM yourTable t1
ORDER BY ts;
```

Comment: sorry I didn't explain my issue I rewrote the question Thanks!

Comment: Did you actually try my code?  It answers your question.

Comment: i'm running MYSQL 5.6.1 couldn't function

Comment: @AboodJayyousi I have added a version which should work on MySQL 5.7

Comment: You need to first fix your data model.  Without a third column providing some kind of ordering, it makes no sense to speak of "first."

Comment: just fixed my database and it works thanks